# ASP.NET Core Web API Minimal connection getting reset after 10 seconds

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET Core .NET 6.0 project with a very simple minimal Web API instance hosted on IIS. I have resource constrained devices connecting to it to POST information and read the response from the server. The problem is that the time for the device to receive the information takes a little while because it is running on an 8 bit processor. So, the connection keeps getting reset at exactly 10 seconds from the initial TCP connection. Using Wireshark, I am seeing that the server is the one issuing the RST. I have tried configuring the Kestrel WebHost parameters:

```
   builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
   {
      serverOptions.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
      serverOptions.Limits.RequestHeadersTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
   });
```

Those parameters seem to have no effect and I can't find any details on a timeout limit from IIS or on the Kestral server. Anyone have any suggestions or recommendations for what to change? Or where the 10 second timeout limit is coming from?

Comment: Are you experiencing the same issue when hosting project without IIS?

Comment: No. If I run in debug there does not seem to be a timeout. Most of the documentation says that most timeouts are disabled when the debugger is attached to the process. So, in theory, I should be able to adjust those same timeouts, right?

Comment: You don't need debug to deploy ASP.NET Core app without IIS

Comment: I can run the app in stand alone mode and it works just fine. No timeouts here either. So, it must be IIS that is adding the 10 second reset timeout. I will look through web.config options to see if there are things to tweak there.

Comment: How you host the app in IIS out of process or in process?

Comment: `inprocess`. I am using the default published web.config. All the timeouts that I have found use defaults of 2 minutes or more. I am wondering if it is the nature of the slow connection that is causing the resets? I was looking at `webLimits` settings but my web.config doesn't even have an `applicationHost` section, so I don't think this applies.